# sorting a counter in python by keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a counter that looks a bit like this:

```
Counter: {('A': 10), ('C':5), ('H':4)}
```

I want to sort on keys specifically in an alphabetical order, NOT by `counter.most_common()`

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: A Counter is basically just a dictionary, so this should really be considered a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key

Comment: Do you want to print them in a sorted order?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just use [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter({'A': 10, 'C': 5, 'H': 7})
>>> counter.most_common()
[('A', 10), ('H', 7), ('C', 5)]
>>> sorted(counter.items())
[('A', 10), ('C', 5), ('H', 7)]
```

Comment: I agree, knowing that the iterator on a dict yields the keys, not the values, then the keys will get sorted.

Comment: Note, this transforms Counter to a list

Comment: @crypdick, Yes it does, and it should be. Because In `Python < 3.7`, the order dictionary key is not guaranteed. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html , https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html

Comment: @crypdick and if you want it as a sorted dict in python >=3.7, just put `dict()` around it

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter({'A': 10, 'C':5, 'H':4})
>>> sorted(c.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
[('A', 10), ('C', 5), ('H', 4)]
```

Comment: This works, however, itemgetter is useful to sort a list of tuples or a list of list, but on a dict it is useless, sorted(c) is equivalent to sorted(c.keys())

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(counter.items(),key = lambda i: i[0])
```

for example:

```
arr = [2,3,1,3,2,4,6,7,9,2,19]
c = collections.Counter(arr)
sorted(c.items(),key = lambda i: i[0])
```

outer:
    [(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (9, 1), (19, 1)]
if you want to get the dictionary format,just

```
dict(sorted(c.items(),key = lambda i: i[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

To get values as list in sorted order

```
array              = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
counter            = collections.Counter(array)
sorted_occurrences = list(dict(sorted(counter.items())).values())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can use the [most_common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) function of collections.Counter:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
counts = collections.Counter(x)
counts.most_common(len(counts))
```

This uses the most_common function available in collections.Counter, which allows you to find the keys and counts of `n` most common keys.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. I get `[('c', 3), ('d', 2), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)]` which is not sorting the keys alphabetically.

Comment: The OP clearly knows about `most_common`, it's mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my comments below

```
# input data
counter = Counter({'A': 10, 'C': 5, 'H': 7})
# Sorting the Counter by keys
sorted_counter = sorted(counter.items())
# change it back into a counter
result_counter = Counter(sorted_counter)
```

the result should look like this:

```
Counter({'A': 10, 'C': 5, 'H': 7})
```

i know the input data and the output data is the same,
but when u change to "ate" then

```
{"a" : "1", "t" : "1" , "e" : "1" }
```

will change to:

```
{"a" : "1", "e" : "1" , "t" : "1" }
```